# future proofing rails partials calling scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm porting a php app to rails and am wondering what the best practice for having the most flexibility in a rails partial is. I saw a lot of "you could do it like this"

I'm thinking like this:

```
<%=render :partial => 'shared/show_info', 
    :locals => { 
        :info => x , 
        :hide_location => true} %>
```

where use a :locals even if only one argument.

Any ideas on whether this would be the best way for maximum scalability in the future or why this would not be a good idea?

thx

edit #1
added the shared/_show_info.html.erb  - this would be the type of thing I'd be doing :hide_location which takes out the location

```
<% if !local_assigns.has_key? :hide_location %>
  <%=info[:location] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this looks good: you use locals and no instance variable. Nothing much to add though

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. Anyway, replace `if !local_assigns.has_key? :hide_location` by `unless local_assigns[:hide_location]`